# OpenGl: Error, The loaded object takes the same colors and style of the Texture?

Tags: opengl, c++, textures

I'm new to OpenGl Faced this problem:

[image: The Glitch]

Draw function:

```
void Renderer::Draw()
{

    glUseProgram(programID);    
    shader.UseProgram();

    mat4 view = mat4(mat3(myCamera->GetViewMatrix()));                                
    glm::mat4 VP = myCamera->GetProjectionMatrix()*myCamera->GetViewMatrix(); 
    shader.BindVPMatrix(&VP[0][0]);                                           

    glm::mat4 VP2 = myCamera->GetProjectionMatrix() * myCamera->GetViewMatrix() * floorM;
    model13D->Render(&shader, scale(100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)); // scaling the skybox

    t2->Bind();
    model3D->Render(&shader, scale(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f)); //scaling aircraft

    glUniformMatrix4fv(VPID, 1, GL_FALSE, &VP2[0][0]);

    mySquare->Draw();

}
```

The code of loaded:

```
    shader.LoadProgram();
    model3D = new Model3D();
    model3D->LoadFromFile("data/models/obj/Galaxy/galaxy.obj", true);
    model3D->Initialize();
    myCamera->SetPerspectiveProjection(90.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 10000000.0f);


    model13D = new Model3D();
    model13D->LoadFromFile("data/models/obj/skybox/Skybox.obj", true);
    model13D->Initialize();
    // Projection matrix : 
    //shader.LoadProgram();

    // View matrix : 
    myCamera->Reset(
        +0.0f, +0.0f, 5.0f,// Camera Position
        +0.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f,// Look at Point
        +0.0f, +1.0f, +0.0f // Up Vector
        );
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    std::string Images_names[6];

    Images_names[0] = "right.png";
    Images_names[1] = "left.png";
    Images_names[2] = "top.png";
    Images_names[3] = "bottom.png";
    Images_names[4] = "back.png";
    Images_names[5] = "front.png";
    t = new Texture(Images_names, 0);
    t2 = new Texture("arrakisday_dn.tga", 1);
```

Comment: What API are you using?

Comment: @Vaillancourt - we can assume from use of glUseProgram and glUniformMatrix4fv in the "Draw program" section, plus the "opengl" tag, that the API is OpenGL.

Comment: @LeComteduMerde-fou Yes, but I believe `Model3D` and `Texture` are not; if they're part of another API, it would be nice to know which one.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you either have the wrong texture bound when you attempt to draw the airplane, or you're referencing the wrong texture unit when drawing it.

Some things to check:

- Are you calling `glBindTexture()` before drawing the plane? If not, then whatever texture was last bound will still be bound, and it will assume that's the texture you want to use.
- If you are binding a texture, is it the right one?
- If it is the right one, is your shader using the same texture unit in its sampling calls?
- If all the above is correct, then perhaps you're storing all your textures in one big image and you've used the incorrect texture coordinates on the aircraft?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you want to unbind things as soon as they are finished being used to make it clearer which object is currently bound. After you draw your Sandbox/terrain try to do `glBindTexture(gl_texture_target, 0)`. This will also prevent the wrong texture to be sent to the shader.